# Modulus of a complex number depending on a parameter

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

How to solve |2 + t + t*i|$^2$? I know the formula for z = x + iy, then |z| = $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$

Comment: Is the parameter $t$ real?

Comment: There's nothing to solve: you've just an algebraic expression...

Comment: Why don't you stay connected once you have asked a question ? You would have answered the basic question of @J.G.

Comment: I have taken the liberty to suppress the adjective "weird" which is nonsensical : this is a very simple complex number. More generally, prefer understatement to overstatement.

Comment: The t is real, 0 <= t <= 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For complex $t$ we have $$z:=2+(1+i)t\implies |z|^2=zz^\ast=(2+(1+i)t)(2+(1-i)t^\ast)\\=4+2tt^\ast+2(t+t^\ast + i(t-t^\ast))=4+2|t|^2+4(\Re t-\Im t).$$

Comment: @Mark Bennet Thanks. I correct my answer.

Comment: I think that the OP has forgotten to say that $t$ is real. In this case, the answer is plainly $(2+t)^2+t^2$

Comment: Thank you, dear contributors!